# AdHoc build not getting archived with Titanium SDK 3.2.0

Tags: xcode, titanium, ad-hoc-distribution

I have implemented cross platform application using Titanium 3.2.0 but when i try archiving the build for iOS AdHoc distribution, it does not get compiled. It keeps giving error with developer name as mentioned below - Invalid "--distribution-name" value ""
I tried building from XCode, Titanium UI and over Terminal as well but same error everywhere. I have referred https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-5642 and it says that issue is fixed but i still face this issue over every machine updated to 3.2.0 or even when 3.2.0 is installed fresh.
Please help and provide information.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Application IDs don't match from your project to your Provisioning Profile.

In your Tiapp.xml file, you may have and application id like com.mycompname.THISappname, but you told the Apple Provisioning Profile that your app id was called com.mycompname.OTHERappname.  So they don't match.  Change your Tiapp.xml file to match the what the Apple Provisioning Profile expects or creating another profile matching your application id in Titanium Studio.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:  create a new production certificate AND create a new provisioning profile with the same bundle ID. (Yes, this will work if you are updating an app that is already live). Download the cert and prov. profile and run both (double click). Now repeat step 6 and archive. This should work.